# PhpExcel - How insert the same row after row N?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have php template. this is a empty table (T0 rows) with some footer at the bottom.
From php i try to fill the table, but if i had T1 rows (T1 > T0) then trouble appers.

I beleve that empty table should contains one empty row. And we know this row number.
Then we copy this row (insert the same rows) T1 times and fill empty table. Footer goes down. And everything will be ok

Give me an example, how i can do this. Thank you.

PhpExcel 1.7.6

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(2,10); Insert 10 new rows between rows 1 and 2

Comment: MANY THANKS, Mark! It works! But now need to apply style of row 2 for these rows

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1'),'A2:A10); will copy the style from cell A1 and duplicate it to cells A2, A3, A4.... A10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just copying what @markBaker said (so that we can set the solution as an answer):

```
//Insert 10 new rows between rows 1 and 2 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(2,10);
```

Now applying the style of the row 2 to the inserted rows:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1'),'A2:A10');
```

Comment: The code for applying style containers a **zero-width non-joiner (&zwnj;)** character between the characters 'g' and 'e' in the `getStyle()` method, giving a hard to identify error in that line.