# PHPExcel - copy range of columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have Excel file where I need to expend space by duplicating excat column range.

[image]

I upload a part of that file that can be seen in a picture. I need to copy row from A16 to H16 and set it right below (A17 to H17) so it would automatically move other columns below.

This is one of examples I hvae tried. None of them work.

```
   $appPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
        $webPath = realpath($appPath . '/../web/uploads/statements/the-file.xlsx');
    $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($webPath);

        $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(16,16);
        $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A16'), 'A16:H16');

    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');
    $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
    $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'the-file.xlsx'
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

    return $response;
```

Api call works, to be exact, it donwloads that file with updated edits but the part with copying rows doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the parameters and the example on [PhpExcel - How insert the same row after row N?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069986/phpexcel-how-insert-the-same-row-after-row-n) I would assume your parameters are incorrect, I think `insertNewRowBefore()` has parameters insert point and number of rows, so this should be 16 and 1 in your case.  Also the `duplicateStyle()` call should be with the rows you want to update and not the range of cells - I've put 'A15', but this may need to be tweaked.

```
    $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(16,1);
    $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A16'), 'A15');
```

**Update:**

If you want to copy the data as well, I've rewritten it to cut down the repetitive bits, but start with the row you want to copy.  This then inserts a row before this and then creates a range which covers all of the row using `getHighestColumn()` to get the end of the row.  It then copies this range for you.

```
$copyFrom= "4";
$activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$activeSheet->insertNewRowBefore($copyFrom,1);
$activeSheet->duplicateStyle($activeSheet->getStyle('A'.($copyFrom+1)), 'A'.$copyFrom);
$lastColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
$rangeFrom = 'A'.($copyFrom+1).':'.$lastColumn.($copyFrom+1);
$activeSheet->fromArray($activeSheet->rangeToArray($rangeFrom), null, 'A'.$copyFrom);
```

Comment: I tried like that and it works! Thanks. I have just one problem. I want to copy whole row, how I can set infinity range. I want to copy whole 16th row. I don't know how to explain.   @NigelRen

Comment: I have read it. But I can't figure out syntax. I it's more advanced for me. :) I hoped there is simple way for start. @NigelRen

Comment: I've updated the answer - first time I've used PHPExcel so it has been interesting to try.

Comment: This is genius. Thanks a lot! :) @NigelRen